# Xcode - Error when try to run app

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

I'm trying to run an ionic app in xcode.
I ran it several times but in certain momento it doesn't compile and returns me this error : 
`linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

```
2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVLogger
```

I try several things, like:

- Go to product and clean
- Close xcode and restart the computer
- Recompile ionic
- In setting put the bicode = no

To open xcode I run the `app xpto.xcworkspace` file.
And nothing solve the problem, how can I solve that?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try searching through the ionic github? Looks like this is the fix: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12849#issuecomment-328472880

Comment: You need to check this class CDVLogger dependencies